# CSS overlay troubles with google chrome

Tags: css, linux, google-chrome, opacity

I'm using google chrome 5.0.307.9 beta under ubuntu 9.10 and it seems not properly render css opacity.

Using "opacity: 0.5;" under both windows chrome or windows/linux firefox make my element half transparent, but this attribute seems ignored on linux chrome. This was working on previous versions.

Any ideas about what's going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure this is a bug in google chrome itself.  using opacity: 0.5 is totally valid CSS markup, and it will work on the windows [and mac?] versions of chrome.

For now, all you can do is... try using a different browser [firefox/safari/konqueror], or ignore that your div isn't partially transparent until the fix comes.

I know that isn't really a solution, but I don't think there is much that you can do =/
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the build, I noticed problems in a VM a week ago with this, update your chrome to resolve, current release is **5.0.322.2**  Fixed it on the VM here at least, hopefully the same for you.

Comment: just updated to 5.0.322.2 and still having the problem :/ Thanx for your help ;)

Comment: Seems this only happens to Chrome on Linux, so I don't think there's a way to fix this until Google does. I wouldn't try too hard to make it work anyways as this seems a temporary issue. Also if I were you, I'd inspect that element -- maybe Chrome uses another defined opacity to override it?